# Insert raw HTML into Elm component

Tags: elm

How do I insert text - that I know to be 'safe' - directly into an Elm page.

i.e. what is `text'` in the following.

```
let str = "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
in div [] [ text' str ]
```

In practise I could get any valid HTML, so I don't want to build a parser, and I'd rather avoid a port as playing around wit the DOM can break the virtual dom diffing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few solutions discussed in this [post](https://m.reddit.com/r/elm/comments/49w48m/inserting_html_from_api/). Seems the poster had success with using `Markdown.toHtml`.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36677911/1023963), this is what worked for me:

Install the markdown library

```
elm-package install evancz/elm-markdown
```

To render your HTML in a `div`

```
import Markdown

div [] [ Markdown.toHtml [] str ]
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Elm 0.19, it appears that the hole in elm-markdown has been plugged and properly escapes HTML.

A solution that works with Elm 0.19 is to parse the HTML using [hecrj/html-parser](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/hecrj/html-parser/latest/):

```
import Html.Parser
import Html.Parser.Util

let
    rawHtml = "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
    innerHtml = case Html.Parser.run rawHtml of
        Ok nodes -> Html.Parser.Util.toVirtualDom nodes
        Err _    -> []
in
    div [] innerHtml
```

Comment: elm-markdown now escapes HTML by default. You can still get the old behavior using the options: https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-explorations/markdown/latest/Markdown#Options

Answer (score 0):

Or simply this [as per](https://github.com/eeue56/elm-for-web-developers#can-i-enter-html-as-a-string):

```
import Html exposing (div)
import Html.Attributes exposing (property)
import Json.Encode exposing (string)

main = 
  div [ property  "innerHTML" <| string "<div>hello</div>"  ] []
```

Comment: The site where you got this from specifically says don't use this idea